# Ethernet Issues

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I have a router with 4 ethernet ports, only one works (the rest are disonnected and can't be reconnected by me). I was searching for a workaround and I found Ethernet Switches.

Can an Ethernet Switch be connected to the port that's working on my router and allow me to share the connection to any other devices I want to add to the connection via the switch?

Comment: Short answer is yes. Longer answer is why can't any of the other ports work? If there is a serious network issue (hardware or software), putting a switch in place will not help.

Comment: make sure your devices are getting private (LAN) IPs. its conceivable that the reason the lan ports are disabled is that it is operating in bridge mode, and if you connected multiple devices you might get more than your share of public IPs. if you find your devices are getting public IPs then placing a router in line (instead of a switch) may be the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your router (unless defective) is likely the ISP Modem with Router and the working port is the one they supply.

Do ensure the router hardware is good.  Try a hardware Reset back to out of the box settings. It seems unlikely 3 ports would be defective.

So yes.  You can add an Ethernet Switch to this working port and connect other Ethernet Devices as you desire.

I have done this with an ISP Modem / Router and it works just fine.

Get a good name brand Switch (3-Com, Netgear, HP).